# How to capture output from docker build in PowerShell on Windows 11

Tags: docker

I am attempting to capture the output of `docker build` when executed from a PowerShell script on Windows. If I pipe the output, say to `Tee-Object`, I get:

> failed to get console mode for stdout: The handle is invalid.

The build works, but I get no output saved. Same happens if I redirect instead of pipe.  I'm using `--progress plain`.

I need the output in a log file in case the end user of the script (a developer) has issues.

How I can I save the output of `docker build` to a file when executed from a PowerShell script on Windows?